# How to know when the Lib-GDX SoundManager crashes?

Tags: libgdx

When using Lib-GDX html, how can I know when the `SoundManager` crashes. It sometimes crashes because of flash errors and I would like to reload my website when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it is pretty simple, all you have to do is setup a listener and wait for the alert to appear. I do not know if this has any other dangerous consequences, but this was bugging me and I found a solution, I want to make sure future users know about it.

```
function check() {
    var node = document.getElementById('embed-html'),
    htmlContent = node.innerHTML;
    if(htmlContent.includes("canvas")){
          document.getElementById('logodiv').style.display = 'none';
    }else  if(htmlContent.includes("gwt-TextArea gwt-TextArea-readonly")){
          window.location.reload();
}
```

and put that in a timeout:

```
setTimeout(check, 100);
```